# vue.js function only working if value is greater than zero

Tags: vue.js

I have the following function that is formating font colour based on the value returned. The value returned is from a GraphQl non-nullable field and is in a range from 0-10. It works perfectly if the value is 1-10, if the value is zero it does not run as expected.

```
formatFont: function (state) {
        
        if (state) {
           if (state >= 0 && state <= 6) {
              return 'red--text';
           } else if (state >= 7 && state <= 8) {
              return 'orange--text';
           } else if (state >= 9 && state <= 10) {
              return 'green--text';
           } else {
              return 'white-text'  // i.e. white on white = invisible
           }
        } else {
           console.log('Output else')
           return 'white--text'  // i.e. white on white = invisible
        }
     }
```

If the value is zero it will return the else statement, I have a solution to increment each value by 1 which resolves but it feels like a hack, I want to understand why it doesn't recognise zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

`if (state) {`

to

`if (typeof state !== 'undefined') {`

why because `0` is `falsey`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a= 0
var b= '0'
var c= 1

if(a) {
console.info('a',a)
}
if(b){
console.info('b',b)
}
if(c){
console.info('c',c)
}
```

Because of the **0** as a false consider but you pass as a string then it will go the true.